# Solve an equation with a variable in the power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:

$2hr^{2}+2r^{2-\nu}-\ell^{2}=0$

and would like to solve for $r$ in terms of $h$ and $\ell$ given that $1<\nu <2$ (and then later, but not as importantly right now $\nu > 2$).  Is there a simple way in which I can do this but am missing?

Comment: I would recommend numerical methods.